# Is there a JavaScript menubar widget that allows menu items to be added and removed dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for a JavaScript menu bar widget that allows menu items to be added and removed dynamically.  I'm already loading jQuery and jQueryUI, so any library that builds on those libraries is preferable to one that requires another underlying framework.  A lightweight library with few dependencies is OK too.

The [jQueryUI mebubar widget](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/38666403/Menubar) seems to have the functionality that I need (menu bar, sub-menu support, presumably theme-able) *except* the ability to add and remove menu items easily.  I've started looking into how to hack this ability into this widget, but it's turning out to be more complicated than I expected.  A library that already has this feature would be easier.  (Failing that, perhaps I'll open another question asking how to best hack this widget.)

So, to sum up what I'm looking for:

- JavaScript pull-down menubar widget (click to pull down a menu)
- Sub-menu support
- Customizable appearance
- Arbitrary JavaScript hooks to run when a menu item is selected
- Builds on jQuery and/or jQueryUI, or is lightweight/independent
- Allows menu items to be added or removed dynamically
- License allows commercial use
- Accessibility and keyboard support would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kendo UI includes a nice menu widget: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html. The API looks fairly robust and simple.

The only thing I see missing that you noted is keyboard navigation - also note that there is a cost to use it in commercial projects.

Comment: Hm, KendoUI is pretty big (300K at least, it seems) but it does have a supported API for adding and removing menu items—the first I've seen!  So thanks you for that.  I'll eventually accept this answer if I don't see any better ones.

Comment: It does look pretty heavy, one would only hope you could bundle the necessary widgets you need and create a much smaller package.

Comment: Kendo UI has a packager so you can get only what you need. The 300K is the whole shibang.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use JqueryUI menubar and just append/remove li elements with jquery like this:

```
$("#youreUlID").append("<li id='someID'>.........</li>");
$("#someID").remove();
```

Comment: That's what I hoped to do, but unfortunately it seems that those humble list items undergo significant transformations on their way to becoming menu items.  Just sticking in a new li doesn't trigger all the setup magic that happens when the menu is initially built.  But yes, a hack solution would be to find out how to get all that to happen (binding events, re-numbering items, adding attributes, etc.) on demand.  I'm trying to avoid that since it seems quite complex and fragile.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought that there was some refresh method to be called after append or remove. I found it in todos. So maybe in next version.

Comment: You can re-create the whole menu after adding items dynamically, for example $("#menubar").menubar("destroy").menubar().

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI, Menus do not support dataSource yet, as a work around you can create the HTML bits with C# function;  Here is are the bits, on how to do it, with Model data ;   you can RenderPartial  like @Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/NavigationalControl.cshtml",Model);

NavigationalControl.cshtml

```
@model MenuItemModel
<div id="navMenu" class="k-content">
    <div id="navigationMenu">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script> var menu = null;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#menu").kendoMenu({ dataSource: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(GetMenu(Model.MenuItemFinal)))});
        });
    </script>

    @functions
    {
        public class Menu
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string imageUrl { get; set; }
            public List<Menu> items { get; set; }
        }
        private List<Menu> GetMenu(IEnumerable<MenuItemUI> items)
        {
            return items.Select(item => new Menu()
                {
                    text = item.MenuText,
                    url = String.Format("/{0}/{1}{2}", Convert.ToString(ViewData["LanguageCode"]), Convert.ToString(ViewData["CountryCode"]), item.URL)
                    ,
                    items = item.Children != null && item.Children.Any() ? GetMenu(item.Children) : null
                }).ToList();
        }
    }
</div>
```